# iPhone 4s irregularly asks for Apple ID after a night at airplane mode

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, alarm

My girlfriend uses her iPhone to wake her up, and during night, she puts it in flightmode (because she doesn't like radiation).
1 out of approx. 3 mornings the phone doesn't wake her, instead it asks her (silently) for her Apple ID.
The screen shows (in Dutch, so probably not 100% right translated)

> activation required

after clicking at it, it tells

> Activation required.
>   On your iPhone flight mode is active. Turn off flight mode to continue activation.

and after clicking this it asks for her Apple ID. After filling it in, just than the alarm clock goes off (off course to late :(
Strange behavior, especially since I have used this iPhone for a year (it used to be mine), without any of these problems.

Perhaps beneficial information: she has her own Apple ID, but for apps we share an Apple ID.
[iOs 7.04 on iPhone 4s 32GB]

Comment: Can you please verify the error messages etc. she is getting and add these to your question? It seems as if activation somehow hasn't been completed but without the exact error message that's difficult to diagnose.

Comment: @patrix - just now see your comment, sorry. Somehow it looks like activation, although it is completed already, has to be done again (and again).

Comment: @SibeJan Please provide a screenshot if possible.

Comment: @Robuust - Thanks, but a screenshot is not possible, since the problem does not exist anymore. The above mentioned messages are pretty much what was shown on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped was to order and place another SIM-card :)
I discovered this after succesfully using the phone without a SIM card at all for awhile (without any troubling messages).

Answer (score 0):

Does not answer question directly as this is possibly a bug with flight mode. Her use case is not what flight mode was made for though?  Better option to keep from being disturbed at night is to Use the Do not Disturb feature form settings.   Configurable and can set it to do automatically during certain times.  Otherwise just manually put the phone in mute mode.

On the flight mode...  I know certain older version of IOS had problems with alarms.   Think it is quite possible that the lack of any network connectivity might block some background processes so can think that it would be reasonable to expect the password at some times.   If it stops n alarm from activating it would be a bug in iOS though.

Comment: Avoiding radiation is exactly what flight mode was made for :-) I do the same every night and the alarm goes off in the morning without problems.

Comment: Thanks, Joop, for trying to answer. In 'Do not disturb' mode, i believe the phone still gives radiation, so that's not an option, isn't it? Second explanation is still strange (and only a vague idea, perhaps you could make it more relevant with some reference?), since it never happened to me, while i used it in the same sleeping way. Only difference: 2 instead of 1 apple ID's. So that's why i flagged it as 'this answer is not useful' (haha, but i couldn't). (i'm sorry, I don't want to be offensive - thanks again for trying to help). @patrix do you use 1 or 2 Apple ID's?

Comment: @SibeJan 2 (one for iCloud, one for Apps)